# How to run mac application automatically in fullscreen

Tags: xcode, macos, webview, fullscreen

Hi I like to run an OSx View with an WebView init in fullscreen (so big as the current screen is not the Lion fullscreen mode), is there any code for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
int width = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width;
int height = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height;

[yourWindow setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height) display:YES];
```

the int `width` and `height` will get your screen width and height, and then you set the frame of your window (the one that has your webview) using those ints. 

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: please, click on the check on the left side of this question to accept it! thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry this is a little late, but the easiest way to do it is:

```
[yourWindow toggleFullScreen:@""];
```

Just put this in your `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching`, and it will automatically go into fullcreen. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8, OSX 10.10, the only working code I can find is the following, placed in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
[[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] toggleFullScreen:nil];
```